# Constructores en java

Tags: java

Hola amigos disculpen estoy estudiando java y en las clases el profesor tocó el tema de los "constructores java" y la verdad no entendí bien.

Bueno lo que entendí es esto:

> Un constructor es similar a un método pero sólo sirve para
>   inicializar objetos, no devuelve ningún tipo de valor de retorno y un constructor sirve para inicializar el valor de un objeto.

Comment: un contructor no tiene retorno, sirve para iniciar un objeto nuevo con estado

Comment: Osea,ejemplo: Milibros objeto : New
Milibros(); ,segun como he leido un
objeto se inicia null pero un
constructor crear el objeto y le
establece los atributos
,información ? Eso?, no cuentas
con algun manual de java
constructores? Disculpa soy novato

Comment: con estado me refiero a inicializar atributos de la clase

Comment: Gracias por todo,pero una pregunta por ejemplo si tengo un constructor  con los atributos iniciaLizado : Id ,nombre,edad,pero por  ejemplo  si en un momento del programa debo cambiar esos  atributos,debo crear Otro constructor,eso no sería sobre  carga ? Y tendrá mal rendimiento mi programa ?

Comment: el contructor genera el estado inicial solamente, de seguro que habra cambios en tus atributos pero de eso se encarga los metodos que son las acciones

Answer (score 12):

En java un constructor es una especie de método que te permite inicializar los atributos de una clase.

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    public Persona(){

    }

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellido){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    // Getters y Setters irían aquí abajo ...
}
```

Como puedes ver en la clase persona existen dos constructores, uno sin parámetros

```
  public Persona() {  
  }
```

y otro con parametros

```
public Persona(String nombre, String apellido){
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.apellido = apellido;
}
```

La clase Main quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persona persona1 = new Persona();
        persona1.setNombre("Antonio");
        persona1.setApellido("Morales");

        Persona persona2 = new Persona("Luis", "Veliz");

        System.out.println(persona1.getNombre());
        System.out.println(persona2.getNombre());
    }
}
```

La salida sería esta:

```
Antonio
Luis
```

Como podrás darte cuenta para el objeto persona2 no tuvimos que acceder a los métodos get y set para darle valor a sus atributos ya que lo creamos a partir del constructor con parametros.

En una clase puedes tener cuantos constructores quieras siempre y cuando los parámetros que reciban sean diferentes a los de otros constructores, ya sea en cantidad o tipo, es decir en la clase persona podríamos tener:

```
public Persona(String nombre){
    // Código
}

public Persona(String apellido, int cualquierVariable){
    // Código
}

public Persona (Boolean cualquierOtraVariable) {
   // Código
}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Lo que entendiste es correcto!

> Un constructor es similar a un método pero sirve para inicializar
>   objetos no devuelve ningún tipo de valor de retorno

#### La definición de la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctor.html) nos dice:

> Un constructor se utiliza en la creación de un objeto que es una
>   instancia de una clase. Generalmente lleva a cabo las operaciones
>   requeridas para inicializar la clase antes de que los métodos sean
>   invocados o se acceda a los campos. Los constructores nunca son
>   heredados.

#### En base a esto podemos definir características y diferencias con respecto a un método:

- Un constructor siempre debe tener el mismo nombre que la clase.
- Un constructor no tiene un tipo de retorno por lo cual no devuelve algún valor. Un método puede o no tener un tipo de valor de retorno.
- Un constructor es llamado al crearse una instancia de un objeto, y esto solo se realiza una única vez, a diferencia de los métodos que pueden ser llamados en múltiples ocasiones.
- Los constructores nunca son heredados, ya que no son considerados como miembros de clase. Esto es una diferencia importante con respecto a los métodos ya que estos si podrían ser heredados.
- Cuando heredamos de una clase base, si no se declara un constructor, java automáticamente llama al constructor por defecto de la clase que heredamos.

#### Este es un ejemplo de una clase donde hacemos referencia al constructor:

```
public class Pais { 

    private String nombre; //propiedad nombre de cada objeto Pais. 
    private int cantidadHabitantes; //propiedad cantidadHabitantes de cada objeto Pais. 

    //Constructor, cuando se cree un objeto Pais se ejecutará el código incluido en el constructor, como sabemos sirve para INICIALIZAR.
    public Pais (String nombre, int cantidadHabitantes) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidadHabitantes = cantidadHabitantes ;
        //Puedes inicializar también con un valor fijo. 
        //this.nombre = "México City";
        //this.cantidadHabitantes = 125000;
    } 

      //Getters/Setters
      //método para obtener nombre de pais en el objeto Pais.
    public String getNombre () { return nombre; } 
    //método para asignar nombre pais en el objeto Pais.
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
            this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    //método para obtener cantidad de habitantes de pais en el objeto Pais.
    public int getCantidadHabitantes () { return cantidadHabitantes; } 
    //método para asignar cantidad de habitantes de pais en el objeto. 
    public void setCantidadHabitantes(int cantidadHabitantes){
            this.cantidadHabitantes = cantidadHabitantes;
    }


}
```

Agrego un interesante articulo en español: **[Definición de constructores de una clase.](http://www.mundojava.net/definicion-de-constructores-de-una-clase.html?Pg=java_inicial_4_4_5.html)**

---

Agregue al objeto los métodos get y set, los cuales son simples métodos que usamos en las clases para mostrar (método get) o modificar (método set) el valor de un atributo en la clase
.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios ,disculpa una última pregunta ¿ que get y set? Mientras leeia los note  que los agregaste ?
Si no es mucha molestia me gustaría  saber?

Comment: No es molestía, son conceptos que debes conocer,  agregue a mi respuesta que son los métodos get y set, saludos.

Answer (score 6):

**¿ Qué es un Constructor?**

> Es un bloque de código similar a un método que se llama cuando se crea una instancia de un objeto .

**¿ Qué lo diferencia de un Método ?**

- Un constructor no tiene un tipo de retorno.
- El nombre del constructor debe ser el mismo que el nombre de la clase.
- A diferencia de los métodos, los constructores no se consideran miembros de una clase.
- Un constructor es llamado automáticamente cuando se crea una nueva instancia de un objeto.

**Estructura de un Constructor**

```
 /* La palabra reservada public indica que otras clases 
    pueden tener acceso al constructor */
 public NombreClase (TipoDato nombreparam1,TipoDato nombreparam2) 
    /* Parametros Separados por Coma */
 {
     /* Declaraciones y/o asignaciones */
 }
```

> Un constructor permite proporcionar valores iniciales para los campos(atributos) de la clase cuando se instancia un objeto.

```
 public class Persona {
   /* Atributos */
   private String nombre; 
   private String apellido;

  /* En el Constructor de la Clase Persona Inicializamos  los atributos 
      nombre y apellido  asigname a nombre el valor de name que es enviado
        al instanciar un Objeto de la clase Persona */
  public Persona(String name, String lastname)
  {
   this.nombre = name;
   this.apellido = lastname;
  }

}
```

Las Instancias se crean de la siguiente manera , esto hará que se llame automáticamente al constructor que recibe dos parámetro de tipo `String`

```
Persona per = new Persona("Nombre1", " Apellido1");
/* tu objeto Persona tendrá sus atributos nombre= Nombre1 y 
   apellido = Apellido1 */
```

Para Leer un Poquito más a fondo esto , es importante y siempre imprescindible leer la documentación.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctor.html

Algo más a fondo
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html

Comment: He notado que muchas cosas que escribes son tomadas de otros autores, [por ética es importante dar crédito a las fuentes de donde tomas la información](http://es.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Elenasys con * antes y despues se hace cursiva, con ** se hace negrita

Comment: Siempre puedes editar tu respuesta y empezar con ésta

Answer (score 3):

su funcion es inicializar los atributos y objetos que tiene una clase ya que si no se inicializan puede provocar una excepcion del tipo NullPointerException veamos un ejemplo

```
public class Ciudad{
  private int codigo;


  //aqui el constructor
  public Ciudad(){
   codigo="123"; //asignaste el valor 123 a la variable codigo

   //tambien puedes ejecutar otros metodos esto se hace generalmente cuando quieres que se ejecute una accion al arrancar la aplicacion por ejemplo que muestre un mensaje de bienvenida en consola
   System.out.println("bienvenido");
  }
}
```

si creas un objeto de esta clase veras que se inicializa el codigo en 123 y se muestra el mensaje en la consola suerte!

Answer (score 2):

Segun mi perspectiva y con el fin de aportar a tu duda

Un constructor, como su nombre lo dice, es un bloque de código que se encarga de crear una instancia o inicializar un objeto de una clase determinada. Cada clase tiene o debería tener ciertos atributos que lo diferencian de otras clases (por ende de otros objetos). Los constructores no tienen tipo (void, static, etc) ni tampoco retornar un valor, su función es siempre inicializar todos las propiedades o atributos de la clase en cuestion. No necesariamente siempre tienen que llevar valores especificos, por ejemplo, un valor de una propiedad si lo deseamos (aunque no veo bien el caso) podemos iniciarla como null en caso de objetos, en 0 en tipos numeros o en "" en tipos de texto. Hay dos tipos de constructores, con y sin parametros.

Ejemplo :

Tenemos una clase llamada Auto con dos atributos(o propiedades) : Placa y Marca

Observacion : Si tu no le das un modificador de acceso (private, public, protected) por defecto solo la clase propia y el package pueden acceder a esa propiedad.

1. No especificado

   - Puede acceder : La clase y el Package
2. Private

   - Puede acceder : solo la clase
3. Protected

   - Puede acceder : La clase, el package y una subclase (en caso de herencia)
4. Public

   - Puede acceder : Todos (Clase, subclase, package, etc)

Ejemplo :

```
public class Auto{
    String placa;
    String marca;

    public Auto () {
    }

    public Auto (String placa, String marca){
        this.placa = placa;
        this.marca = marca;
    }
}
```

En este caso particular, los parámetros de entrada de el constructor tienen los mismos nombres de las propiedades de la clase. Por eso utilizo el `this` para hacer referencia especifica a las propiedades de tu clase, aunque tambien puede ser asi :

```
public Auto (String placaAuto, String marcaAuto){
    placa = placaAuto;
    marca = marcaAuto;
}
```

Para la creación de un objeto tipo Auto, como te explique arriba dependiendo del modificador de acceso es como lo puedes crear

Si los indicadores de las propiedades llevan public o no llevan puede ser

```
Auto nuevoAuto = new Auto();
nuevoAuto.placa = "HV-45-78";
nuevoAuto.marca = "Chevrolet";
```

O

```
Auto nuevoAuto = new Auto("HV-45-78", "Chevrolet");
```

Ambas formas son validas y te ayudaran a instanciar un objeto de tipo Auto, espero que te ayude esta información y complementar a los que las demas te dieron.

Answer (score 1):

Un constructor proporciona el estado inicial de un objeto. Piensa en un objeto, por ejemplo, la clase Auto con propiedades: `Marca`, `Modelo`, `Kilometraje` y `Color`.
Cuando creas un objeto de esta clase tienes que dar los valores para esas propiedades
Ejemplo:

```
Auto carro1= new Auto("Ford", 2012, 56000, "verde")
```

al dar esos valores el objeto se construye con esas características.

Esta instrucción `new Auto("Ford", 2012, 56000, "verde")` llama al constructor y le dice los valores que tendrá el objeto `carro1`

Answer (score 0):

Todo es muy simple, más de lo que parece. Una variable Java almacena referencias a objetos, lo que de toda la vida se le ha llamado puntero. Inicialmente, sin inicializar contiene basura, a saber, será un elemento poco seguro de usar.

Necesitar disponer de un objeto, pero sólo puedes obtenerlo a partir de un constructor, el cual es el mecanismo que te permite crear la referencia que guardará la variable. Gracias al constructor, se reserva el espacio de memoria del puntero y se le otorga los valores iniciales con los que el objeto comienza a funcionar.

El constructor, por tanto, es el medio por el que se obtiene objetos para una clase.

Answer (score 0):

Proporcionar constructores para
las clases Una clase contiene
constructores que se invocan
para crear objetos a partir del
modelo de clases. declaraciones
de constructores se ven como
método declaraciones, salvo que
se utilice el nombre de la clase y
no tienen ningún tipo de
devolución. Por ejemplo, la
bicicleta tiene un constructor:
Bicicleta pública (int
startCadence, int Startspeed, int
startGear) {engranajes =
startGear; cadencia =
startCadence; velocidad =
Startspeed; } Para crear un nuevo
objeto de bicicletas llamado
myBike, un constructor es
llamado por el nuevo operador:
Bicicleta myBike = new bicicletas
(30, 0, 8); newBicycle (30, 0,8)
crea un espacio en la memoria
para el objeto e inicializa sus
campos. A pesar de bicicletas
sólo tiene un constructor, que
podría tener otros, incluyendo un
constructor sin argumentos.

Gracias por los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Yo también soy nuevo en esto de programación, pero comparto lo que entiendo:

El constructor, como efectivamente dice tu profesor, INICIALIZA los valores de los atributos que tiene tu clase e inicializa el objeto.

¿Qué quiere decir esto?

Acordate que las variables y objetos son APUNTADORES. Pensalo como un ROTULO, que nosotros usamos para identificar x variable y poder usarla correctamente en nuestro programa PERO, PERO, PERO!!! para la computadora, ese "ROTULO" contiene una "dirección" (en hexadecimal)la cual le dice en que ESPACIO de la memoria esta guardado el valor de nuestra variable para ella saber a donde tiene que ir para buscar el valor que nosotros queremos y no otro.

Cuando creamos/INSTANCIAMOS un objeto, se le RESERVA ESPACIO en la memoria para todos los parámetros que este contenga. EJ: clase Persona tiene: String nombre, String apellido,  int edad, boolean sexo, etc... Se les reserva un espacio en la memoria para cada uno de estos parámetros y se los inicializa.

2 COSAS:

1. Cuando declaramos que una variable, por ejemplo "String nombre" es igual a NULL (nombre = null;). Le decimos que nuestro rotulo/APUNTADOR NO esta APUNTANDO a ningún LADO! Es decir, que no tiene dirección en memoria, por lo que no EXISTE en nuestra memoria. Es decir, no esta "inicializado"... ¿Utilidad de esto? Null se usa mucho para las estructuras de datos dinámicas (listas, arboles), donde el uso correcto del modificador null es vital para no entrar en bucles infinitos cuando se instancia un nodo.
2. Los tipos de datos PRIMITIVOS, si no los instancias, adquieren un valor por defecto.
   Es decir, byte, int, long, double, float, boolean, char, etc, todo estos tiene un valor por defecto, como los boolean que por defecto se instancian en false.
   Pero los tipos de datos estructurados o de CLASES, como el caso de nuestro querido STRING (String es un objeto, cuando le das valor a una variable String, esta crea una CADENA (String) de caracteres (char) y crea un objeto) DEBEN SER INICIALIZADOS, sino cuando los quieras usar en tu programa (sin estar inicializados), te va a arrojar el error: NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION, es decir que nuestro apuntador no va a apuntar a ningún lado, porque no se le asigno valor cuando creamos nuestro objeto.
   Si  lo  pensas, esto es lo que pasa con un ARRAY, cuando declaramos el tamaño, pero no lo inicializamos/recorremos espacio x espacio para asignarle valor.

EN RESUMEN

Así que el constructor, lo que hace es RESERVAR ESPACIO EN LA MEMORIA para nuestro OBJETO
otorgándole a cada uno de sus campos un valor por defecto (el cual definimos nosotros en el constructor, EJ: edad = 0;), los cuales luego podremos MODIFCAR a antojo para hacer, lo que sea que queramos hacer en nuestro programa.

Comment: El constructor no es exactamente quién reserva espacio en la memoria. Al ejecutar una sentencia con el operador `new`, la máquina virtual reserva en el heap el espacio correspondiente en función del tamaño de la clase. Una vez se ha reservado ese espacio, se inicializan los atributos que se hayan definido con el operador de asignación (ej: private Date fecha = new Date();) y finalmente se llama al constructor. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-operator-java/

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección y la información... Se aprende algo nuevo cada día. Gracias de nuevo.